# TestCase To Detect DatabaseError: no such column

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-testing

I recently added a new field to one of my models and forgot to add the appropriate column to the table in the database. I have test cases that test adding a new instance of this model and changing an existing instance. Neither of these test cases failed. Yet when I try to change an instance with the live site I get

> DatabaseError no such column

I have made some attempts to detect this error from within a TestCase but no such luck.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you (I really, really hope) don't use your production database for testing with, so all that you could detect is that the column doesn't exist on your test database, which is (presumably) recreated from scratch based on your model definitions, not that the column is missing from your production database.

A better approach to this problem is to use a migration tool like [South](http://south.aeracode.org/), and automate the deployment process so that migrations are run as new code is deployed.

This will only work for small(ish) sites - you might find naively running migrations causes pain if you've got a high-traffic site. If you're in that situation, you may find David Cramer's [write-up on schema changes](http://justcramer.com/2011/11/10/scaling-schema-changes/) informative.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunetly, using `syncdb` command is not enough to update the database.

You can insert the fields manually with your database management system or use a solution like [South](http://south.aeracode.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Use following link it as very well explanation for your problem.

http://amionrails.wordpress.com/2013/11/17/django-databaseerror-no-such-column-error/